# Storing userid into sessions

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a login.html and processlogin.php. I want to store the userid from login.html into processlogin.php by using sessions. After that, i would wish to display welcome "userid" in my index.html. I want to know whether it is possible to do it and how should i do it. Currently, processlogin.php is using the post method to retrieve data from login.html and checks with the database whether the user is in the database.

**Login.html**

```
        User id: <input type ="text" name = "userid" required>
        Password: <input type = "password" name = "password" required>
```

**processlogin.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "shoes");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM user WHERE userid=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($p);
$stmt->fetch();
if($p == $password)
{
    echo header('Location: index.html');
}
else
{
    echo '<p><h1>Login unsuccessful!</h1>';
    echo "Please <a href='login.html'>Click Here</a> to go back to login.";
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: you can't print php variable in html page. You have to use ajax to get the session value or you have to make it .php file and then use echo $_SESSION to get the value

Comment: You can't send form data using sessions. Sessions only exist on the server, not on the client. `processlogin.php` can set the session variable after it processes the form, and then it can be used in other scripts. But you have to use a `POST` variable to send the userid to the server.

Comment: @Barmar how do i set the session variable after it processes the form ?

Comment: `$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;`. Have you read any documentation on PHP session variables?

Comment: @Shubhranshu so by using ajax, i would be able to get the session value and print in on a html webpage?

Comment: Yes. But after creating session. I mean when you are done with the login. then you have to send an ajax request to get the session value

Comment: But it will be easy if you create this page in php

Comment: @Shubhranshu create which page in php ? Do you know the code for requesting the session value?  Right now i have to store it into session first, before i use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

We can't print use any PHP variables in HTML page.

To Get UserId In Login Page, we need to convert login.html in to login.php
or Redirect to index.php after successfully login.
Save user id in php session Variable.
Example:- 
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userId;

Comment: so in processlogin.php, i have to add $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid; ? shouldnt i add $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_POST['userid']; ?

Comment: @EddieLee I think the feasible solution for you is to convert html page into php. And after that you can access session variable which is suggested by Himani.